# How to prevent CP 3000+ pokemons from losing motivation unreasonably quickly?

Tags: pokemon-go

It seems like Pokemon above CP 3000 lose motivation much more quickly than pokemon below CP 3000. Is there any way to prevent this?

As of now, most my defenders will just decay of their own very quickly, even when not attacked, and this is super frustrating.

Is this difference in rate of motivation decay a bug? Or is it documented somewhere with descriptions of how to mitigate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not a bug and the way to prevent is well - feed it berries. Higher CP Pokémon, by design, lose motivation faster than lower CP Pokémon

This [article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/06/pokemon-go-how-quickly-do-pokemon-lose-motivation-loss-formula/) states

> First of all, it’s important to note that Pokemon lose motivation gradually over time, even if they are not defeated in battle. The exact formula depends on the Pokemon, but Pokemon with higher CPs lose motivation quicker than Pokemon with lower CPs. This is something that has been confirmed by Niantic.
>
> “To help balance different Pokémon strengths and abilities, stronger Pokémon generally lose motivation more quickly than those that are not as strong,” [Niantic said on its website](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009004687).

[Niantic Support](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009004687)

> To help balance different Pokémon strengths and abilities, stronger Pokémon generally lose motivation more quickly than those that are not as strong.

Comment: Wow... That's pretty terrible game design... Firstly, being above 3000 CP does not make the pokemon strong. A 2900 Blissey is much stronger than a 3600 Tyranitar. Secondly, it's a bit annoying that Niantic are essentially giving the middle finger to everyone who spent millions of hard-earned stardust to power up pokemons. Pretty stupid design by them. Anyways... Thanks for the references to those articles!

Comment: @Alderath Keep in mind that this type of gym system has been out for less than 24 hours - there are bound to be things that need improving :)